# How to parse date/time with dots/periods golang

Tags: datetime, go, parsing, time

How do I parse date/time string with dots/periods `01.08.2022 17:00:02`

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "time"

func main() {
    date, err := time.Parse("2.Jan.2006 15:04:05", "01.08.2022 17:00:02")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(date)
}
```

This results in `panic: parsing time "01.08.2022 17:00:02" as "2.Jan.2006 15:04:05": cannot parse "08.2022 17:00:02" as "Jan"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct format is:

```
date, err := time.Parse("2.1.2006 15:04:05", "01.08.2022 17:00:02")
```

The `Jan` in format will require the month name spelled out instead of a number.